# Which of the 2 claims are wrong and which is correct? Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $ V $ be an inner product space.

Which of the following 2 statements are correct?

1.For each 2 subspaces $ S,T\subset V $ if follows that if $ S^{\perp}=T^{\perp} $ then  $ S=T $ - I think that this is the correct statement, but according to the lecturer who solve the test that I took this question from, this is the false statement.

The second statement:

2.For each subspace of $ V $ exists an orthonormal bases (the vector in the bases are orthogonal to eachother, and each vector $ v $ follows that $ ||v||=1 $

Now I think that 2 is incorrect, because what about the zero subspace? does it have an orthonormal base?

I'll show also my "proof" for the first statement.
I'll "prove" that $ S=T $ :

fix $ s\in S $ then for each vector $ v \in T^{\perp} $ it follows that $ <s,v>=0 $ because $ S^{\perp}=T^{\perp} $.

Thus,  $ s\in\left(T^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=T $ so $ S\subseteq T $.

In the same way we show that $ T\subseteq S $ and thus $ S=T $.

What's wrong with my proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(T^\perp)^\perp = T$ is wrong in general.

Comment: For point 2, the empty set is an orthonormal basis for the zero subspace

Comment: @Jan can you give a counter example?

Comment: @Waizman https://mathoverflow.net/q/53330, OP gives a counterexample in the "Edit".